# checking if a data.table is keyed in a function, R

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to check if a `data.table` that my function is operating on is `key`ed.  How does one do this? For example:

```
x = data.table(a=1:100, b=100:1)
setkey(x, a)
f = function(v) {v+1}
x[,f(b),by=a]
```

I would like to check *inside* `f` if there is a key set on `x` and what that `key` is

This would require access to the object that `f` was called from, in this case `x`. Is this possible in `data.table`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f = function(v) {
    cat("haskey(caller's x) is",eval(quote(haskey(x)), sys.frame(2)),"\n")
    # x in line above = name of first argument to `[.data.table`
    v+1
}
DT = data.table(a=1:3,foo=1:6)
DT[,f(foo),by=a]
haskey(caller's x) is FALSE 
haskey(caller's x) is FALSE 
haskey(caller's x) is FALSE 
   a V1
1: 1  2
2: 1  5
3: 2  3
4: 2  6
5: 3  4
6: 3  7

setkey(DT,a)
DT[,f(foo),by=a]
haskey(caller's x) is TRUE 
haskey(caller's x) is TRUE 
haskey(caller's x) is TRUE 
   a V1
1: 1  2
2: 1  5
3: 2  3
4: 2  6
5: 3  4
6: 3  7
>
```

But why would you need that?

Comment: But is there any way to do this if you don't already know that the name of the `data.table` being subsetted is going to be `x`?

Comment: @Josh. It wasn't relying on it being called `x`. Edit clarifies hopefully.

Comment: @Matthew Dowle: The reason I want to use this is I have a utility function that lags things within a group (so by permno for example). This is just a function that does `head` or `tail` depending on the sign of th lag so it's nothing complicated. To work correctly though, the data.table must be sorted by a date. So I want to check this in the function to make sure.

Comment: If there is a better way to do this I'd be eager to hear about it (in reference to the method i use for lagging things mentioned in my comment above)

Comment: @MatthewDowle It certainly does clarify it. Very clever!

Comment: @Alex Then I doubt you need to check whether the caller is keyed. Lagging and rolling within group is fairly standard. Might need a different new question to see what you mean.

Comment: @MatthewDowle: ok, let me setup a new question.